# Laravel Tests are getting failed on laravel 9.4 and php 8.1 (Filament Form error)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-filament, php-pest

Recently I updated the Php version of my app, and now the tests are getting failed.

it is giving me the following error:

Declaration of Filament\Support\Components\ViewComponent::view(string $view): static must be compatible with Illuminate\View\Component::view($view, $data = [], $mergeData = [])

at D:\portal\vendor\filament\support\src\Components\ViewComponent.php:25

```
     21▕     protected string $view;
     22▕ 
     23▕     protected string $viewIdentifier;
     24▕ 
  ➜  25▕     public function view(string $view): static
     26▕     {
     27▕         $this->view = $view;
     28▕ 
     29▕         return $this;
```

In ViewComponent.php line 25:

I couldn't think of any solution to this. should I update the filament form version?

Comment: Update your Filament - https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/5181